# multiple foreach loops in html table

Tags: php, html, css, sql

In my database i have 2 tables.

Axle table:

```
 ______________________________________
| axle_id | train_id | axle | distance |  
|_________|__________|______|__________|   
|   1     |     1    |   1  |    20    |
|   2     |     1    |   2  |    50    |
|   3     |     1    |   3  |   200    |
|   4     |     1    |   4  |    50    |
|   5     |     1    |   5  |   200    |
|   6     |     1    |   6  |    50    |
|   7     |     1    |   7  |   200    |
|   8     |     1    |   8  |    50    |
|_________|__________|______|__________|
```

Bogie table:

```
 ___________________________________________
| bogie_id | axle_id | train_id | bogie_nr |  
|__________|_________|__________|__________|   
|    1     |    1    |    1     |    1     |
|    2     |    2    |    1     |    1     |
|    3     |    3    |    1     |    2     |
|    4     |    4    |    1     |    2     |
|    5     |    5    |    1     |    3     |
|    6     |    6    |    1     |    3     |
|    7     |    7    |    1     |    4     |
|    8     |    8    |    1     |    4     |
|__________|_________|__________|__________|
```

Now i want to show these results on my page in a table like this:

```
 _____________________
| bogie_nr | axle    |  
|__________|_________|   
|    1     |    1    |
|    1     |    2    |
|    2     |    3    |
|    2     |    4    |
|    3     |    5    |
|    3     |    6    |
|    4     |    7    |
|    4     |    8    |
|__________|_________|
```

I tryed doing this with this code:

```
<table id="end_result_axle_bogies">
    <tr>
        <th>Train Axles</th>
        <th>Train Bogies</th>
    </tr>

    <!--Show the end result!-->
    <?php
        $show_end_table = $database->axles($_GET['train_id']);
        $show_end_table2 = $database->bogies($_GET['train_id']);
        foreach($show_end_table as $end_axle_table){ 
            echo "<tr>" . "<td>" . $end_axle_table['axle'] . "</td>";
        }
        foreach($show_end_table2 as $end_axle_table2){ 
            echo "<td>" . $end_axle_table2['bogie_nr'] . "</td>" . "</tr>";
        } 
    ?>
</table>
```

The output works (Shows me the correct information). But the table does not work well. It shows me this result:

[image: End results Shown]

(Made the text green to see if the div is working. wich does).

Does anybody know how to make the table work correctly?

Comment: Change the foreach. Like you do now, it's <tr><td>1</td><tr><td>2</td>... Echo all in one foreach is the better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $show_end_table = $database->axles($_GET['train_id']);
    $show_end_table2 = $database->bogies($_GET['train_id']);
    $table2 = "";
    foreach($show_end_table2 as $end_axle_table2){ 
        $table2[] = $end_axle_table2['bogie_nr'];
    } 
    foreach($show_end_table as $key => $end_axle_table){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $end_axle_table['axle'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $table2[$key] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

Change the foreach. Like you do now, it's `<tr><td>1</td><tr><td>2</td>`... Echo all in one foreach is the better way.

Comment: The $end_axle_table2 is undefind here because it is not in the foreach, Can this be fixed??

Answer (score 0):

May be following code works for you....

```
<table id="end_result_axle_bogies">
<tr>
    <th>Train Axles</th>
    <th>Train Bogies</th>
</tr>

<!--Show the end result!-->
<?php
    $show_end_table = $database->axles($_GET['train_id']);
    $show_end_table2 = $database->bogies($_GET['train_id']);
    foreach($show_end_table as $end_axle_table){ 
        echo "<tr>" . "<td>" . $end_axle_table['axle'] . "</td>";
    }
</table>
<table>
foreach($show_end_table2 as $end_axle_table2){ 
        echo "<tr><td>" . $end_axle_table2['bogie_nr'] . "</td>" . "</tr>";
    } 
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Changed a little bit, it show 2 tables now. but i would like to have them in 1 table if that is posible

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Fetch all bogie_nr and respective axle_id from  bogie table
and then make for loop like

```
foreach(bogie_nr as bogie)
 <tr>
     <td> show bogie_nr </td>
     <td> Fetch axle for respective axle_id of bogie_nr from axle table
     </td>
 </tr>
 end for loop
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a MySQL View ([info here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)) and then looping through the 1 view in a foreach loop instead of you doing 2 database calls.